# "wrong variable or address: " in sasm debugger

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, sasm

I am learning x86-64 assembly, using SASM IDE and I have this question.

```
%include "io64.inc"

section .data
string2 db "hello",0

section .text
global CMAIN

CMAIN:
    mov rbp, rsp; for correct debugging
    mov rsi, string2
    xor rax, rax
    ret
```

Since I `mov rsi, string2`, I thought `rsi` and `string2` hold the same thing, **an address** .

When debugging, I watch `$rsi` and check the "address" box, it shows the char array correctly. But when I also watch `string2` and check "address", it gives `Wrong variable or address: "string2"`. If I uncheck "address", it shows the char array correctly.

Why `$rsi` and `string2` behaves differently? Did I miss something?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but make sure you preserve `rbp` otherwise you may get a crash later.